# How to run powershell code in every virtual machine in the host

Tags: powershell, vmware, powershell-4.0, esxi

I am newbie to powershell, I have a powershell script That should be run on every virtual machine in my host at same time. One of my friend told me that there is a tool which is developed by Phillips but i searched for it but unable to find. can some one help me with solution are there is any tool for that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you ask your friend the name of the tool? also this is soooo vague i can't even (c)

Comment: My friend also not sure about the tool name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your script inside a script block and run it while enumerating the VMs.

```
# On the host, Get-VM get's you the available VMs.
$runniungVMs = $Get-VM -State 'Running'

foreach ($vm in $runningVMs) {
  Enter-PSSession $vm
  # Write Some code to execute after this line
}
```

## You can also use a script block inside a loop if you can get the actual computer name of the VM:

```
Invoke-Command –ComputerName <computerName> -Credential  $Cred –ScriptBlock {
  # Write some code to execute
}
```

**Update on additional questions**

The **Get-VM** command gets the list of virtual machines available on the host where the command is running.

If your VM host is not the machine you are running on you can specify the computer name of the VM host. Here is how to get the list of running VMs on Server1:

```
Get-VM -ComputerName Server1 | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Running'}
```

Posh also comes with great help. If you need to find out more about any command you can use:

```
get-help Get-VM
```

or

```
get-help Get-VM -examples
get-help Get-VM -detailed
get-help Get-VM -full
```

Comment: +Ben Richards  Thanks for your answer. If you don't mind can you please help me with the information about power shell tool. Is there any tool developed by Phillips to run Powershell scrips, or is there any other  tool to run powershell script.

Comment: Yes, there are probably a dozen tools to *develop* Posh (official Powershell abbreviation) scripts. You don't need a tool to run Posh scripts as the Posh environment already comes built into Windows. I don't know the one by Phillips, but Windows 7-8-10 come with a decent IDE for writing Posh scripts. It's called Windows Powershell ISE. It should be already installed on your Windows machine.

Comment: Does above code run every time when we power on the virtual machine? What if we what to run code only once? And with out giving the host name where the vm's are running, how the code executes on that vm's in the host

Comment: No. You asked for code to run on several VMs, not to run on every VM every time you power on the VM. If you want to run some code every time the VM powers on, you will have to put that code inside the operating system on the VM itself. If you give me some details on what you are trying to accomplish, maybe I can give you a better answer..

Comment: I don't want code to run every time VM powered ON. Answer you given is perfect, but How the code knows to run on the VM's on the particular host powered ON.Because we did not given any  Host related information in script. Where we need to save  our Powershell script? and how to manage configuration between Host and Script. Thanks for your patience.